# How to find out server model on a VPS

Tags: vps, virtual-machines

I have a rented a vps server and I would like to find out the brand and model of this server, for example: Dell Poweredge 2950

Thanks

Comment: Unless the host server is improperly configured, you can't.

Comment: tell me more, please

Comment: Ask your provider.

Comment: 1. Why don't you ask the provider? 2. Why do you want to know? Out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the virtualization platform being used, you might be able to see what model of CPU is being used, simply by looking at what model of CPU is visible to the VPS.

You can also look for the MAC address of the network interface on the machine hosting the VPS. How to do that depends on whether the virtualization platform is configured to route or bridge network traffic.

If it is routing, you need to perform a traceroute from the outside to the VPS. If the last hop before the VPS has an IPv6 address generated from a MAC address, that will be the MAC address of the physical machine.

If it is bridging, you need to look at MAC addresses visible from the VPS itself. On the virtual interface look at all the MAC addresses on the LAN. Look up each of them, ignore the virtual ones, find just those that are physical network interfaces. Of those, the one with the lowest roundtrip time is probably the machine the VPS is hosted on.

Those are the only methods I know of. I don't think there are any other methods apart from exploiting a security vulnerability in the virtualization platform.

You can of course also just ask the hosting provider.